# How to obtain uniform bounds on a polynomial by looking at its coefficients.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, polynomials

To be more precise, let $p:[0,1]\to \mathbb R$ be a polynomial of degree $n$. Picking a basis of polynomials (e.g. monomials based at $0$), we can represent $p$ $$p(x)=\sum_{j=0}^na_jx^j,$$ for some unique coefficients $a_j\in \mathbb R$.

Now, as $p$ is a continuous function on a compact set, it is bounded. I would like to be able to obtain relatively sharp information about the bound on $p$ by looking at the above coefficients, $a_j$. For example, one has $$\|p\|_{\infty}\leq\sum_{j=1}^n |a_j|\leq n\max_j|a_j|.\quad(\star)$$ But in general, this will clearly be a bad bound as one can have polynomials with many large (in absolute value) coefficients which manages to be small due to cancellations of positive and negative coefficients.

---

So my (unfortunately rather vague) question is how can one get bounds sharper than the brute-force $(\star)$? Ideally, something that doesn't rely upon the one-dimensional nature of the domain. Perhaps [see Olivier below] my life would be easier with a different choice of basis polynomials?

Comment: The bound is sharp. So what is your hope here?

Comment: @MooS Clearly, if I knew the bound was sharp, I wouldn't ask the damn question! Would you mind expanding your comment?

Comment: The bound is sharp, but that doesn't mean it can't be improved! In the Bernstein polynomial basis, the polynomial is bounded by its greatest coefficient. +1 to the question.

Comment: @Olivier That sounds very interesting, actually. Do you have a reference? The wikipedia page on Berstein polynomials doesn't seem to show it!

Comment: I'll give you the proof. A bernstein polynomial takes the form $\sum_{i=0}^n c_i B_{i,n}(x)$, $i \in \{0,1, \dots, n\}$, where the $B_{i,n} \geq 0$ are the basis functions and the $c_i$'s are the coefficients. It is known that $\sum_{i} B_{i,n}(x) = 1$. Hence, $$\sum_{i=0}^n c_i B_{i,n}(x) \le \max_j c_j \sum_{i=0}^n B_{i,n}(x) = \max_j c_j.$$
You also have a similar lower bound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no one obvious way to get a good bound on the maximum of a polynomial on $[0,1]$, but a few tricks can help you.

**Optimization.**
The maximum of $p$ is given by 
$$
\|p\|_\infty = \max \{p(0), p(1)\} \cup \{p(z) \,|\, p'(z) = 0\}.
 $$
Sometimes, you may be able to determine that $\{p(z) \,|\, p'(z) = 0\} = \emptyset$ (e.g. using location-of-zeros methods such as [Descarte's rule of sign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_rule_of_signs) and [Sturm's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%27s_theorem)). Otherwise, if you're not able to calculate $\{p(z) \,|\, p'(z) = 0\}$, you can still bound $p$ by a lower degree polynomial and apply the above method.

**Change of basis.**
In the Bernstein polynomial basis, a bound on the maximum is given by the largest coefficient.

**With numerical methods.** If you're able to locate the zeros of $p'$ with some accuracy, then you can use the above methods to bound the polynomial $p$ restricted to small interval around the zeros of $p'$. This will give you (rigorous) bounds that you can get to be as good as you want.